# Columnwise heatmap in seaborn

Tags: pandas, seaborn

Seaborn heatmap applies the heatmap across all rows and columns. how can I have the heatmap applied columnwise, i.e. so the max value per column is brightest - for instance to see the busiest hour per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that is to normalize the data in each column. First let's generate some data for the example:

```
# Generate some data to show example

import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(8)

days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
hours = list(range(8,18))

example_peak_hour = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 12, 7, 3])
data = [p*example_peak_hour for p in np.random.randint(5, 50, len(days))]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).T, columns=days, index=hours)
```

Plotting it with searborn heatmap and normalizing it with [df.max()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)) :

```
sns.heatmap(sns.heatmap(df/df.max()))
```

[You can check how it looks here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxDl8.png)

Comment: Thanks! What I'm trying ot see though is the max hour per day...I'm updating my question to clarify using your data.

Comment: hold on I'm an idiot. It was just the way the data was generated that made it look weird at first glance. Looks like it does exactly what I need - thanks!